# Could not handle request: /api/identity/recovery/v0.9/recover-password WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to use password recovery in WSO2 IS 5.3.0, I've updated my configuration follow this guidance [https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Password+Recovery ..](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Password+Recovery%20..)

The error when I call this recovery password API

> curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H
>   "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user": {"username":
>   "kim","realm": "PRIMARY","tenant-domain":"carbon.super"},"properties":
>   []}'
>   "https://localhost:9443/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/recover-password?type=email&notify=true"

The error that i got is :

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve} -  Could not handle request: /api/identity/recovery/v0.9/recover-password 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.handleErrorResponse(AuthenticationValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:93)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1729)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there any suggestion about this error?

Comment: Can you please attach the whole carbon logs with error stacktrace?

Comment: does the password recovery works when doing it through the dashboard for the user kim?

Comment: already attached up there

Comment: @ Buddhima Udaranga it got another  error, but no longer null pointer exception

Comment: can you add that error?

Comment: about the connection to smpt host. but, could you please tell me what different between using dashboard and api ? why i got the different error.. is it because the wrong value on my request body?

Comment: SMTP error you are getting should be because of the configurations in the output-event-adapters.xml file related to the email sending smtp server check the recovery using notifications part in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Password+Recovery But for the null pointer you are getting thats not the case

Comment: curl -X POST -k  -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user": {"username": "kim","realm": "PRIMARY","tenant-domain":"carbon.super"},"properties": []}' "https://localhost:9443/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/recover-password?type=email&notify=true"  Use this as the curl request

Comment: Also if you getting any response after curl request attach that too.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue in IS-5.3.0

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5944

Use a IS-5.4.0 or higher version. Otherwise, you can find the fix for this issue in the given URL. [1]

[1].https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-carbon-auth-rest/pull/44/files